# Negotiating salary for a offer in different country

Tags: interviewing, salary, job-offer, new-job, negotiation

After a lot of struggle I finally got selected at a company in Germany. During initial rounds I deferred the salary expectation part partly because I don't know much about German ecosystem as well as I don't wanted to miss the chance. Also, company is bearing the VISA expenses of me and my wife too.

I finally got the offer with HR telling me that there are some areas of improvement specially in the communication part. The HR told me about compensation during the call and asked me if I am ok, that time I said yes but after talking with few of my friends I found that the salary I am being offered is just average salary and whose large chunk will be gone in tax part.

I am married so I was expecting something generous and I was told that they will keep that in mind. Now, I have the offer letter with the compensation on it and I have to sign and send it as soon as possible. I am worried if I can negotiate the salary or not and to what extent and I don't want to loose the offer too.

Also, should I ask them if they can provide me some bonus upfront so that I can manage my expenses for first month including rent etc?

I am really bad at negotiation and I don't want to regret later on.

PS: I can disclose the amount hope it doesn't violates any company policy.

Comment: @MisterPositive as I told the HR reminded that I have some areas to improve but they still want to consider me, what should I infer?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere what are suggestion on the last part?

Comment: "I am married so I was expecting something generous". Does this mean that every single guy should not expect a generous pay only because he is not married. Also if a single guy suddenly gets married - should he expect a larger pay and the most interesting part, if you suddenly will become single - should they just decrease your pay?

Comment: @SalvadorDali now you have just twisted and turned my argument like anything.

Comment: As far as I understood, by "I am married so I was expecting something generous" you meant something like this: 'because I am married, I wanted to get more money'. If no, can you please explain what you wanted to say by that phrase?

Comment: @SalvadorDali I need you need to change your profile pic first.

Comment: how is my profile picture related to that phrase?

Comment: @SalvadorDali its my point of view and I am not concerned what others think because I am the one responsible for my bread and butter, its just a way to show employer that I am not being unreasonable and if I am worth it then I will be listened.

Comment: actually this IS a way to show that you are unreasonable. Things like 'I have a wife, pay me more', 'I bought a dog, pay me more', 'I want a cool car, pay me more',  'my friends are wealthier than me, pay me more' and other non-work related things should not be taken into account by the employer and as far as I know are not taken to the account. Most employers do not see a quality 'being married' as something that will improve the work you do for them, so they do not need to pay more for this.

Comment: @SalvadorDali once again its my point of view because if I had to reject the offer I need to tell them why? its better to tell them that the amount being offered is not enough to run a family.

Comment: Sometimes yes, because now employer should think whether you will ask an increase once you get a child. I wanted to tell you that if you want to negotiate and NOT be rejected, you should find a better leverage. Like in addition to things you need I know A, B, C which will improve our work because of D, E. I was a speaker at conferences F and a mentor at event G which can help you in H. Also I am currently finishing learning the new stuff K, which becomes the proffered way to do the work that your company does in L. This way you improve your chances to get a job and a higher salary.

Comment: @SalvadorDali if you check I already received offer letter and your argument makes no sense at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try resources like Glassdoor to gauge typical salaries.

Unless you are some kind of superstar, don't expect to squeeze them for more unless they have some kind of desparate situation, like they are a startup that has to produce a prototype in 6 months or die. If it is an established company, they will probably not move very much on salary. Even if you get some small concession out of them, they will just get revenge by not giving you a big raise later. (I am stuck in that situation that I have a relatively high salary, so I get 1% raises every year.)

You can always ask for more money later after you are hired. If you are doing an excellent job, just hit them up later for a raise. That is what I did. After I proved myself and was doing a good job for about 6 months, I asked for a raise, and they gave me a raise and a promotion.